# conjure-up openstack zfs

Tags: openstack, zfs, conjure-up

I have installed the openstack one machine with conjure-up, 
in the start up guide "http://conjure-up.io/docs/en/users/#getting-started" said the localhost recommend "250G SSD with a seperate block device for ZFS. Our recommendation for that device is 100G." , how to setup the 100G ZFS block device to be used in openstack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing conjure-up, you need to tell lxd to use the ZFS. 
You can do it by running

```
sudo lxd init
```

You can also point it straight at blockdevice /dev/sdb, if sdb1 doesn't exist. It will create the partition and pool automatically.

[image: picture of the process]

Comment: got following error:

$ sudo lxd init
Do you want to configure a new storage pool (yes/no) [default=yes]? 
Name of the new storage pool [default=default]: 
Name of the storage backend to use (dir or zfs) [default=dir]: zfs
error: The requested backend 'zfs' isn't available on your system (missing tools).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this helps; but I've found useful informations at 
https://www.howtogeek.com/175159/an-introduction-to-the-z-file-system-zfs-for-linux/

If you have a second HD (say /dev/sdb) without any partition table and you want tp create a pool named "geek1" this is the command you have top use:

sudo zpool create -f geek1 /dev/sdb

Answer (score 0):

If you are only configuring ZFS because you think you need to do it for a minimal dev install of Openstack, you can skip that.

From a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04.2:

```
sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
```

Then you can pretty much go "next next finish" through getting Openstack to run inside LXD.  It takes a while to run.  Note the Openstack URL on the last page of the procecss.  Also, from the main host,

```
juju gui
```

is a helpful command.

If not a clean install of Ubuntu, you might have to clean up juju, lxd, or conjure-up.  I prefer the wipe/reinstall method.  But a derivative of the following could be useful:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge juju
sudo apt-get remove --purge conjure-up
sudo apt-get remove --purge lxd
```